# Javascript not working in IE8 or Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a computer that the javascript (such as dropdown menus) does not work in IE8 or Firefox.
Thanks,
JGB

Comment: Not a programming question... or even a question.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point ensure that javascript is enabled in your browsers.